# Android : Updating GUI from service

Tags: java, android, https, android-service, greenrobot-eventbus

**What I want?**

I am looking forward to use service in android and I want to update GUI and also use database from the service.
I came to know about the library called `EVENTBUS by greenrobot`, but I don't know if it is safe to use.

**Why I want?**

Actually I want to write the code for my android in such a way that there is a service running in background doing all the data related work and its responsible for `HTTP calls` and `Database update` from background only and all the fragments only `subscribes` to the events of Service and the service `publish` it when some events occurs. I want to write my code in `Pub-Sub` way.

By doing this I can achieve a `good separation between logic and GUI` related work. Also,  I can have the `re-usability of the code`  by defining all the data related work in the `services` and GUI in fragments only.

Thats why I am looking for some good `pub-sub library` which we can use it  from the service.

Comment: use broadcast reciever with service

Comment: https://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/

Comment: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-intentservice-example-using.html

Comment: read about custom `ContentObserver`s and `ContentProvider`s